Euler-Lagrange equations: Connections between the field theory and point mechanics
As I understand, the Euler-Lagrange equation for a field theory is this:
$$\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \psi^\dagger} - \partial_\mu \left( \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial (\partial_\mu \psi^\dagger)} \right) = 0.
$$
What do the terms in it represent?
Can we connect it to the Euler-Lagrange equation in point mechanics
$$\frac{d}{dt} \left( \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}} \right) - \frac{\partial L}{\partial q} = 0
$$
where we can "simplify" to:
$$m\ddot x-F=0.$$
Can we interpret the terms in the Field theory EL equation similarly as we can in the classical one?

TL;DR: The dictionary between field theory and point mechanics is a follows: The spatial coordinates $x$ in field theory can be viewed as a continuous indices in point mechanics. This analogy becomes even clearer if one replace the continuous space with a discrete lattice, cf. e.g. this related Phys.SE post.
In terms of formulas:

On one hand, a 1st-order Lagrangian in point mechanics is of the form
$$ L(q(t),v(t),t) \tag{PM1}$$
with Euler-Lagrange equations$^1$
$$\begin{align}
\color{red}{\frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial L}{\partial v^j}}~=~&\frac{dp_j}{dt}~\approx~\color{red}{\frac{\partial L}{\partial q^j}}, \cr\cr
v^j~\approx~&\dot{q}^j, \cr\cr 
p_j~:=~&\frac{\partial L}{\partial v^j} 
.\end{align}\tag{PM2} $$

On the other hand, a 1st-order Lagrangian functional in field theory is of the form
$$L[q(\cdot,t),v(\cdot,t);t]~=\int \! \mathrm d^3x~ {\cal L}(q(x,t),v(x,t), \partial_x q(x,t), t),\tag{FT1}$$
with Euler-Lagrange equations
$$\begin{align} 
\color{red}{\frac{d}{dt}\frac{\delta L}{\delta v}}~=~&\frac{dp}{dt}~\approx~
\frac{\partial{\cal L}}{\partial q}-\sum_{i=1}^3\frac{d}{dx^i}\frac{\partial{\cal L}}{\partial(\partial_iq)}~=~\color{red}{\frac{\delta L}{\delta q}}, \cr\cr 
v~\approx~&\dot{q}, \cr\cr 
p~:=~&\frac{\partial{\cal L}}{\partial v}
~=~\frac{\delta L}{\delta v}
.\end{align}\tag{FT2} $$



$^1$ Notation: The $\approx$ symbol means equality modulo eqs. of motion.
